# Error input checkbox, input text en una tabla y agregar datos a un array

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Actualmente tengo un error al momento de recorrer una tabla quiero agregar a un array solo las filas que tengan el checkbox activado, mi código jquery es el siguiente:

```
           var DataArray = [];
            var tableData = document.getElementById("TableDetail");
            for (var i = 1; i < tableData.rows.length; i++) {
                var rowcheked = tableData.rows[i].prop('checked', this.checked).length;
                if (rowcheked > 0) {
                    DataArray.push({
                        brand_id: tableData.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML, //Quiero obtener el valor de un <td>1234</td>
                        amount: tableData.rows[i].cells[4].firstChild.value, //Quiero obtener el valor de una caja de texto dentro de un <td><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"></td>
                        state: tableWarehouse.rows[i].cells[8].val()  //Quiero obtener el valor de un checkbox <input type="checkbox" id="state" name="state" data-boton="1"  data-val="1" @{ if (state > 0){ <text>checked="checked"</text> } }  />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   { <text>checked="checked"</text> } }  />
                    });

                 };
            }
```

Me sale error en la siguiente linea de código:

```
var rowcheked = tableData.rows[i].prop('checked', this.checked).length;
```

También tengo error al obtener los valores de las cajas de texto y el checkbox de la fila que esta activado el checkbox:

```
brand_id: tableData.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML, //Quiero obtener el valor de un <td>1234</td>
amount: tableData.rows[i].cells[4].firstChild.value, //Quiero obtener el valor de una caja de texto dentro de un <td><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"></td>
state: tableWarehouse.rows[i].cells[8].val()  //Quiero obtener el valor de un checkbox <input type="checkbox" id="state" name="state" data-boton="1"  data-val="1" @{ if (state > 0){ <text>checked="checked"</text> } }  />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   { <text>checked="checked"</text> } }  />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según la imagen solo quiero agregar a un array los datos de la fila que esta activado el checkbox.

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar para solucionar mi error y darme algunos alcances.

Comment: Por favor pon todo el código necesario para poder simular tu problema y así crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). También te falta por añadir el error del que tanto hablas.

Comment: @Daes tengo una idea de cual puede ser tu problema pero debes agregar un ejemplo de codigo verificable para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjunto el siguiente código, el cual debería funcionar suponiendo que no utilizas una datatable.

Para este ejemplo utilizo:

1. Una tabla generada con valores random solo por propositos educativos.
2. Jquery.
3. Un evento click para procesar los datos.
4. Un ciclo para crear el objeto que contenga la información de las filas que tengan un checkbox con estado checked

```js
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
row = `<tr>
<td>${i+1}</td>
<td>Marca${i+1}</td>
<td>${Math.floor(Math.random()*394)+79}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxes" name="checkBoxes[]" value="${Math.floor(Math.random()*394)+79}"></input></td>
</tr>`;
$('#example').children('tbody').append(row);
}

$('#btnProcesar').on('click',(e)=>{

let alMenosUnaSeleccion = $('#example tbody>tr').find('input[name="checkBoxes[]"]:checked'),
json = [];
if(alMenosUnaSeleccion.length > 0){
$('#example tbody>tr').each((i,el)=>{
if($(el).find('.checkBoxes').prop("checked")){
json.push({
"brand_id": $(el).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
"cost":$(el).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
"state": $(el).find('.checkBoxes').val()
})
}
})
}else{
alert('seleccione un item')
}
console.log(json)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <th>codigo</th>
    <th>marca</th>
    <th>costo</th>
    <th>estado</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<input type="button" value="Procesar Data" id="btnProcesar">
```

Espero sea de ayuda
Saludos.

Comment: Me fue de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: @DAES de nada amigo